# Slow Queries Not Logging

Tags: mysql, optimization, performance, slow-log

I am attempting to enable slow query logging on our server in order to identify any queries that could use optimization. Sounds simple enough, however my file is not being written to. I get no errors or anything of the like, it just doesn't seem to be logging the slow queries. I have remembered to restart mysql after my config changes.

I am using MySQL Ver 5.1.61 . Here is what I have in my.cnf:

```
slow-query-log=1
slow-query-log-file=/var/logs/my.slow.log
long_query_time=1
```

the file /var/logs/my.slow.log has mysql as the owner, also in the interest of debugging I gave read/write to all on the log file.

I have the long_query_time set to 1 in the above as I just want to see if it is working. I have tried setting it lower(e.g 0.3) but I'm still not getting anything logged. I know that the queries my app are running take longer than 1 second and I've also ran intentionally log queries (`SELECT sleep(10);`) in the terminal for testing and the log is still empty.

I've looked through the docs, from what I can see this should be working. Anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks much!

Edit: As asked in comments I ran the query:

```
 `SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name IN ('slow_query_log','slow_query_log_file','long_query_time');`
```

The result:

```
10.0000000
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld-slow.log
OFF
```

Obviously my configuration changes are not being taken into account as I believe these are defaults. I am quite certain the my.cnf file I am altering is being parsed as if I put in an invalid value mysql will error on restart. What could be going on here?

Another Edit:

After taking @RolandoMySQLDBA 's advice and moving my slow query config lines to under `[mysqld]` my settings seem to be saving. Now the result of the above variable_value query is :

```
1.0000000
/var/logs/my.slow.log
ON
```

However I am still not seeing the file my.slow.log being written to. I don't think it is a permissions issue as the file is owned by mysql **and** I've added all permissions for all users on the file. Could anyone think of a reason why this would not be working?

Edit: Solved! The path to the slow query log was incorrect, it should have been /var/log/my.slow.log instead of /var/log**s**/my.slow.log . Thanks to all for the help, I've learned allot!

Comment: Please run `SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name IN ('slow_query_log','slow_query_log_file','long_query_time');` and post its output.

Comment: If anyone still have issues after reading this, check the log_output variable. `SET GLOBAL log_output=FILE` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I got the answer:

You need to put those options under the `[mysqld]` section

```
[mysqld]
slow-query-log=1
slow-query-log-file=/var/logs/my.slow.log
long_query_time=1
```

and restart mysql

## UPDATE 2013-03-05 16:36 EST

I don't know why this is still happening, but please try this:

```
service mysql stop
rm -f /var/logs/my.slow.log
touch /var/logs/my.slow.log
chown mysql:mysql /var/logs/my.slow.log
service mysql start
```

then run `SELECT SLEEP(10);` and see if it lands in `/var/logs/my.slow.log`

Comment: Thanks!What you suggested helped, it seems the settings are saving properly however I'm still not getting things written. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Hey, just curious, I'm running a Debian system under a VM. Is the path correct in your reply? `/var/logs/` instead of `/var/log`

Comment: Just Info.  "touch & chown" are necessary at CentOS 6.6 mysql 5.1.73 environment also.

Comment: I just ran across a system where they attempted to put these in `[mysqld_safe]`, which did not work. Putting them under `[mysql]` solved the problem.