# MySql Not Logging Slow Queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, performance, slow-log

I've set up slow query logging for MySQL 5.7:

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow_query_log.log
long_query_time = 10
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0
```

Then to test it, I've used MySQL Workbench and ran `select sleep(12);` and then verified that `vim /var/log/mysql/slow_query_log.log` shows that query.

So I thought everything was great. **However, my slow_query_log seems to work *only* for my test queries such as `select sleep(12);` and not for real queries.**

Below is an example. In some spots in my Laravel PHP app, I call `\DB::enableQueryLog();` and then `Log::debug(\DB::getQueryLog());` after running a query, and in those logs I see *extremely* slow queries (241 seconds!?), but I've never seen them in the `slow_query_log.log`.

```
array (
'query' => 'select * from `automations` where (`contact_id` = ? and `job_class_name` = ? and `execute_at` = ?) and `automations`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1',
'bindings' =>
array (
  0 => 23030,
  1 => 'App\\Jobs\\SubscribeToWebinarFollowupEmailSeries',
  2 => '2018-12-30 19:13:00',
),
'time' => 241.37,
),
```

How can I fix this?

<sub>P.S. I don't think my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36003/slow-queries-not-logging) because in my tests the logging *does* work.</sub>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My queries that I thought took 352 seconds really only took 0.352 seconds! ‍♂️

https://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-what-time-format-does-dbgetquerylog-return showed me that Laravel's `DB::getQueryLog()` shows "time" as milliseconds (microseconds multiplied by 1000), not seconds.

What an embarrassing mistake (poor assumption). So I need to edit my 500-point bounty question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469793/e-warning-error-while-sending-stmt-prepare-packet-pid/54374937?noredirect=1#comment95579631_53469793

Answer (score -1):

What is the value of `log_output`?  It should be `"FILE"` or `"FILE,TABLE"`.

For that particular query, do you have a composite index on these:

```
INDEX(contract_id, job_class_name, execute_at, deleted_at)
```

(Any order will do.)

`long_query_time = 10` hardly catches anything; I recommend lowering it.

Comment: 10 seconds because I feared cluttering the logs since I already have so many queries that took 200+ seconds `SELECT @@global.log_output;` says `FILE`. And `select * from mysql.slow_log;` returns 0 rows. Yes, I have 2 unique indexes: 1 is a composite of those first 3 columns, and the 2nd is a composite of all 4 (including `deleted_at`). I've been so confused for weeks (or even months) now.

Comment: Check permissions on all the directories in this path: `App\\Jobs\\SubscribeToWebinarFollowupEmailSeries`

Comment: It's not a path. I have a `SubscribeToWebinarFollowupEmailSeries` PHP class in `app\Jobs\SubscribeToWebinarFollowupEmailSeries.php` with `namespace App\Jobs;`. So `'App\\Jobs\\SubscribeToWebinarFollowupEmailSeries'` is just a string referring to that. I always appreciate your suggestions though.

Comment: If `log_output` is `FILE`, then `mysql.slow_log` could be empty.  Change it to `TABLE` to see if the table starts receiving both `SLEEPs` and that slow query.

Comment: `SET global log_output = 'table'; select sleep(11); select * from mysql.slow_log;` successfully showed the sleep query. So I assume your suggestion now is to leave log_output as 'table' and wait to see what happens with my real-world production queries (see if they appear in the table). I'll probably know on Saturday when I'll have some site visitors again. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, this is driving me crazy. I got a Slack warning saying that a MySql query took 17 seconds (according to `\DB::getQueryLog()` in Laravel), but `select * from mysql.slow_log;` doesn't show it. It still just shows my `sleep(11)` from Jan 2.

Comment: @Ryan - Have you changed the config file, then restarted mysqld?

Comment: Yep, and I've completely restarted the whole server. I can't believe I'm still having trouble with this. I think it's related to a question that I just added a 500 bounty for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53469793/470749